# GQL query Inequality no working with ''IN" operator

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am writing a GQL query that is using both IN operator and inequality operator but it is returning an error. My query is

```
SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE state IN ('ABC') AND count > 9
```

and the output is 
    no matching index found.

```
The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: MYModel
properties:
- name: state
- name: count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the output (and the documentation) you need to create the index for the query to work.
Add the suggestion to your index.yaml

Comment: Thanks Tim , do u know how to do IN operation using filter , instead of gql ?

Comment: Its well documented https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

Comment: its for the ndb type model , i am looking for db .

Comment: If you are starting out, you should try and use ndb over db.  ndb is better (i have projects using both).